# Angular Directive Bug With View

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was doing a very quick exercise with angular directives. My code is very simple.

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('readingList', []);

  app.controller('BooksController', function($scope){

    $scope.books = books;
    $scope.genres = genres;

  })
  app.directive('bookGenres', function(){
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       templateURL: 'partials/book-genres.html'
     };
  });

  var books = [{
   title: 'ABCD',
   author: 'E. Fgh',
   isbn: '123414312341234',
   review: 'Hello world',
   rating: 4,
   genres: { 
     'non-fiction': true, fantasy: false 
   }
 }];

 var genres = ["foo1","bar2","foo2","bar3"];
```

}
**app.html:**

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="BooksController">
  <button class="btn btn-default">Create Review</button>

  <hr />
  <hr />
  <ul class="list-unstyled col-sm-8" >
    <li class="book row" ng-repeat="book in books">
     <aside class="col-sm-3">
       <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/{{book.isbn}}">
         <img ng-src="http://images.amazon.com/images/P/{{book.isbn}}.01.ZTZZZZZZ.jpg" alt="" class="full"/>
       </a>
       <p class="goodRating rating">{{book.rating}}/5</p>
     </aside>

     <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-8">
       <h3>
         <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0553593714" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
           {{book.title}}     
         </a>
       </h3>
       <cite class="text-muted">{{book.author}}</cite>

       <p>{{book.review}}</p>

       <!-- Put Genre Here -->
       <book-genres></book-genres>

       <ul class="list-unstyled">

         <li ng-repeat="(genre, state) in book.genres">
           <span class="label label-primary" ng-show="state === true">
             {{genre}}
            </span>
         </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**book-genres.html:**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">

  <li ng-repeat="(genre, state) in book.genres">
    <span class="label label-primary" ng-show="state === true">
      {{genre}}
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Everything renders with the view except my book-genres directive. For reason, it doesn't work. I have checked the documentation. I checked other similar examples and nothing. If I can't get this directive to work, rendering out the other components such as the image is going to be a problem. I also checked the path of the partials views as well.

Comment: can you provide some sample data to illustrate the problem?  as it stands, this code looks like it should do what you expect, assuming the `books` variable has the proper data.  however, this code doesn't show what `books` contains, or even how it's being set (`$scope.books = books` doesn't make sense on it's own).

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple possibilities here. You need to be sure to inject `$scope` into your controller:

```
app.controller('BooksController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // do stuff
}]);
```

`book.genres` is not defined anywhere, so your `ng-repeat` has no items to display.

`templateURL` is also incorrect, it should be `templateUrl`.

Comment: `book.genres` does not appear to be defined anywhere.. Do you get the ul tag inside the directive or does nothing display at all?

Comment: You're also not injecting `$scope` into your controller so that may be an issue.

Comment: edited my answer with some additional info since you edited your question and my answer no longer made sense.

Comment: Thanks - It was the TemplateUrl issue.